# UI-Router displaying white page without errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router for an app but I cant for the life of me understand why the page is blank. None of the template urls are displaying. Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5vEaAI2jr0rx3c3gkGZ9?p=preview)

**layout.html**

```
<div ui-view="form"></div>
sdagas
<div ui-view="results"></div>
```

**form**

```
This is the form page
```

**results**

Results

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("index", {
    url: "/",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'layout.html',
    controller: 'MainController',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .state('index.layout', {
    abstract: true,
    url: 'layout',
    views: {
      'form' : {
        templateUrl: 'form.html'
      },
      'results': {}
    }
  })
  .state('index.layout.results', {
    url: '/results',
    views: {
      'results@layout': {
        templateUrl:  'results.html'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

app.controller('MainController', function($state) {
  console.log($state);
  console.log('hello');
});
```

Comment: We need to see the HTML structure. This usually results in the way the views are laid out in their various templates.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 In my local it looks like : http://imgur.com/UqG39bO

Comment: no, the actual HTML files and the contents of them. Can you post them here as code.

Comment: @tuckerjt07  the html files are just text. I've posted them anyway. Theyre also in the plunkr.

Comment: Try removing the @layout from results in the app.js view name. Are you attempting to call index.layout by itself? As to Plunkr they are great but for us on mobile it's useless. They don't have a responsive layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [updated a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kX7OeZAhbj7bS9Jgcvpt?p=preview) which is working here

The way how we can call state resuts is:

```
ui-sref 
<a class="brand" ui-sref="index.layout.results">
href
<a class="brand" href="#/layout/results">
```

We can never navigate to state which is abstract. So we cannot go to index or layout

To make the plunker running I also introduced the **`ng-app="app"`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
```

which does start up the app

Also, because the '/' is otherwise but abstract I used another setting to go to some non abstract state

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/layout/results');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

And finally (but almost the most important), this is the updated super child state, which does target the named view not in layout but in index state

```
.state('index.layout.results', {
  url: '/results',
  views: {
    // wrong
    //'results@layout': {
    // this target is in the super parent
    'results@index': {
      templateUrl: 'results.html'
    }
  }
});
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kX7OeZAhbj7bS9Jgcvpt?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no `ng-app` declared in your plunker.. You should have `ng-app="app"` on your html tag.

Secondly, like @Bilal said, you can't have `abstract:true` on the states you want to transition to.

Moreover, your `ui-sref` should point to the states:

```
<a class="brand" ui-sref="index">home</a> 
|
<a class="brand" ui-sref="index.layout">ui-router</a>
```

Here is your updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTDQtDwPphXkj6iEypDi?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

From ui-router wiki:

> An abstract state can have child states but cannot get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its
>   descendants are activated.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

You made root state `abstract: true` so it can't be transitioned.

**Update:**

`ui-sref="/"` should contain state name not the `url` path itself. If you really want to use url path then you should use `href="/"`

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtKceaMcuOMog4bFl17N)

**Update:**

You also missed `ng-app="app"` in your html.

`<html ng-app="app">`

Comment: Change `ui-sref` bug I just mentioned.